# spring batch start job in a specific time

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch in my java application.

I want to schedule a job to run in a specific time, for example - run in 48 hours from now, once only.
How can I achieve that behavior?

Couldn't find anything in the documentation...

Comment: I suppose using a scheduler like quartz

Answer (score 3):

Try Cron Job.

[Link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

If you are using Spring , It has given nice flexibility to the job . Follow [Link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)